# What is the equivalent Python code for the Curl URL. Is there any tutorial that shows how to convert curl to python?

Tags: python, curl, put, hootsuite

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: video/mp4' \
         -H "Content-Length: 8036821" \
         -T "/Users/kenh/Downloads/amazing_race.mp4" \
         "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/3563111_6923ef29-d2bd- 4b2a-a6d2-11295411c988.mp4?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIHSDDN2I7V2FDJGA&Expires=1465846288&Signature=3xLFijSn02YIx6AOOjmri5Djkko%3D"
```

Mainly I do not understand how to user -T line. Headers and URL I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-T` is documented as follows:

```
-T, --upload-file <file>
    This  transfers  the  specified  local  file  to the remote URL. [...] If this is used on an HTTP(S) server, the PUT command will be used.
```

With that in mind, the `requests` invocation, based on [the Streaming Uploads doc](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads), should be approximately

```
import requests

with open("/Users/kenh/Downloads/amazing_race.mp4", "rb") as data:
    resp = requests.put(
        url="https://....",
        data=data,
        headers={
            "Content-type": "video/mp4",
        },
    )
    resp.raise_for_status()
```

Requests will divine the `content-length` header for you if it can.

Answer (score 1):

What your command trying to do is to upload a file to a HTTP server. So `-T` is actually the short version of the `--upload-file` argument and the file name that follows it is the one you want to upload.

`requests` is almost the equivalent package in Python. If you want to convert CURL syntax to Python check [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/#python) site.